# How to get selected values into scope from drop down while using nested ng-option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-options

Following is the view code I'm using to populate multiple select dropdown

```html
<div ng-controller="sourceController">
  <form novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="addNewButton">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add New Data Source</button>
        <div ng-include="'pages/modal.html'"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Location:
        <select id="location" ng-model="location" ng-options="city for (city, facilities) in sourceSelection " style="width: 100px">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Facility:
        <select id="facility" ng-disabled="!location" ng-model="facility" ng-options="facility for (facility, phases) in location">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Phase :
        <select id="phase" ng-disabled="!facility" ng-model="phase" ng-options="phase for phase in facility">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Device Type
        <select id="deviceType" ng-disabled="!phase" ng-model="deviceType">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
          <option ng-repeat="deviceType in deviceTypes" value="{{deviceType}}">{{deviceType}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

  </form>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">click here</button>
  selected choices : {{location}} , {{facility}},

</div>
```

And the controller I'm using is

```js
app.controller('sourceController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
  $scope.sourceSelection = {
    "Chennai": {
      "siruseri": ["phase1", "phase2"],
      "chennai one": ["phase1"]
    },
    "kochi": {
      "Kochi_technopark": ["phase1"]
    }
  };
});
```

Now I want to bind selected field (ie. selected location , Facility , phase in controller)with `$scope` in controller side and model I'm using there is giving me the value of the selected drop down key.

Comment: I don't understand what do you need, could you specify a bit more?

Comment: i am adding fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/sirfabhishek/Lvc0u55v/5534/

Comment: Yeah, but tell us what do you want to do with the values so we can explain you what's next

Comment: i have to pass the selected value to java back end for further processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following two lines are the answer , i got from my colleauge

```
$scope.getSelectedLocation= function(){
        var temp = document.getElementById("location");
        var location = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
      console.log(location);
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the selected value in your controller since you are using ng-model="FIELD" in your select.

So if you want to get the value in your controller you can use:

```
$scope.FIELD // FIELD can be location, phase, facility, etc
```

This variable will store the value of the selected option of each select.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ng-change event to get selected location as,

```
<select id="location" ng-change="getSelectedLocation()" ng-model="location" ng-options="city for (city, facilities) in sourceSelection " style="width: 100px"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
```

In your controller,

```
app.controller('sourceController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {

     $scope.getSelectedLocation = function() {

        console.log($scope.location);
     }
});
```

Comment: its not working you can see the fiddle here    http://jsfiddle.net/sirfabhishek/Lvc0u55v/5536/